# How to schedule a insert script in Oracle 12c DB

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a DB Table and i would like insert statement into this DB table in every 1 hr. Please help

Comment: [Why please help me is not a questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a [**db scheduler**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/scheduling-jobs-with-oracle-scheduler.html#GUID-D41660D0-D88F-4D9F-8CC8-63D040EDC4E6). Have a look at `DBMS_SCHEDULER` there a lot of function that you can use to manage your schduler Job

e.g. you can create a job that will start every hour

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name          =>  'name of your job',
   program_name      =>  'stored procedure that will be executed', 
   repeat_interval   =>  'FREQ=HOURLY; INTERVAL=1',
   start_date        =>   systimestamp, -- when the Job will start first
   comments          =>  'descripn of the job');
END;
```

in a procedure you can specify tast that will be done.

Comment: will it work as below ??
create or replace procedure insert_m3s_dashboard
is
begin
INSERT ALL
  INTO COMMON_INFRA.M3S_DASHBOARD_SCHEDULER (INTERFACE_NAME, FLAG, STATUS) VALUES ('MaterialReceipt', 'N', 'Active')
  INTO COMMON_INFRA.M3S_DASHBOARD_SCHEDULER (INTERFACE_NAME, FLAG, STATUS) VALUES ('InvLevelUpdates', 'N', 'Active')
SELECT * FROM dual;
end;

BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
  job_name     => 'M3S_SCHEDULER_JOB',
  program_name   => 'insert_m3s_dashboard',
  schedule_name   => 'M3S_1hr_schedule');
END;

Comment: do not post a code in a comment. if you want to know if it will work or not, just try ist out.